# Unable to access container url running on vm within internal network

Tags: docker, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cognitive-services

I have an Azure VM on which I have installed speech-to-text service container on port 5000.

When I test the speech-to-text service inside the VM via browser, http://10.x.x.x:5000 it shows the page correctly;

However, when I access the same url on my local laptop connected to internal network, it gives a timeout error.

I have setup network security group rule to allow traffic on port 5000 and verified using IPFlow and there are no blocks;

Just to ensure that this is not a NetworkSecurityGroup firewall issue, I installed nginx container on the same VM on port 80, and I am able to access the nginx default home page within the vm and on my laptop using the url http://10.x.x.x without any issues.

Comment: I think is a reserved port. Try to launch this cmd command to see what are the Port Exclusion Ranges `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have an ubuntu vm, and when I did 
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range, the port ranges was way higher than 5000;  so it doesnt seem to fall within the  Port Exclusion range. I also did cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_reserved_ports and it returned empty

I did a netstat and it looked like docker proxy was using port 5000 (see below)
Proto : tcp6; LocalAddr::::5000; ForeignAddr::::*; State:LISTEN; Program name: 27718/docker-proxy

But, when I browse the container url locally in VM it works;

Comment: Maybe an exclusion port from the Azure ? [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal)

Comment: why dont you try to expose it on some other port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more digging and found that the issue is to do with internal firewall setting blocking non-regular ports (ex:5000).

As a temporary measure I have used SSH tunneling and port fowarding using putty client (based on idea here: akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html).

After establishing the connection using putty, I am now able to specify in my application the speech to text container server as localhost:5000 and it forwards the request correctly to the remote speech to text server.

Meanwhile, i have requested my IT team unblock the port . Thanks for the useful comments Max and 4c74356b41